# How to show that these groups are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

i want to show that $ \mathbb{Z_{36}} \oplus \mathbb{Z_{2}} $ is not isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z_{4}} \oplus \mathbb{Z_{18}} $
at this point im basically listed all 72 elements and am going through find the order of every element it is taking forever there has to be a better way to show that they are not isomorphic.

Comment: But they are isomorphic!

Comment: As mentioned, in this case they are isomorphic. But one of the best ways to show a group isn't isomorphic is to demonstrate that for some $k$, they have a different number of elements of order $k$. That's my go-to approach, and is usually pretty straightforward.

Comment: that is what i was trying to do but it doesn't go so well when they are the same...

Comment: @Faust who told you to show that they aren't isomorphic?

Comment: @KennyLau That's where the problem to show them *not* isomorphic starts to get interesting.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Good joke!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\Bbb Z_{36} \oplus \Bbb Z_2 \cong \Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb Z_9 \oplus \Bbb Z_2 \cong \Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb Z_{18}$$